# Gensim update to W2vec:AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'index'

Tags: python, gensim

**This is my code below and the error I have is beneath it but I cant figure out why this is happening. Please share your thoughts: I checked here https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/wiki/Migrating-from-Gensim-3.x-to-4  but I wasn't able to figure out**

```
word_vec_unpack_idx = [(word, idx.index) for word, idx in \
                   word_vec.wv.key_to_index.items()]
# unpacking vecs tpo create singulrized dataframe 
tokens, indexes = zip(*word_vec_unpack)

word_vec_df = pd.DataFrame(word_vec.wv.syn0[indexes, :], index=tokens)

tokenized_array = np.array(tokenized)
model_array = np.array([word_vec_df.loc[doc].mean(axis=0) for doc in tokenized_array])
model_df = pd.DataFrame(model_array)
# manually adding the label 
model_df["label"] = df_final["Classification"]

display(model_df.head())

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-64-8de619ecbc5b> in <module>
----> 1 word_vec_unpack = [(word, idx.index) for word, idx in \
      2                    word_vec.wv.key_to_index.items()]
      3 # unpacking vecs tpo create singulrized dataframe
      4 tokens, indexes = zip(*word_vec_unpack)
      5 

<ipython-input-64-8de619ecbc5b> in <listcomp>(.0)
----> 1 word_vec_unpack = [(word, idx.index) for word, idx in \
      2                    word_vec.wv.key_to_index.items()]
      3 # unpacking vecs tpo create singulrized dataframe
      4 tokens, indexes = zip(*word_vec_unpack)
      5 

AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'index'
```

**I broke the code down and removed idx so the first part of the code is:**
now the error is gone.

```
word_vec_unpack = [(word, index) for word, index in \
                   word_vec.wv.key_to_index.items()]
# unpacking vecs tpo create singulrized dataframe 
tokens, indexes = zip(*word_vec_unpack)
```

**Now I get another error for the second part of the code**

```
word_vec_df = pd.DataFrame(word_vec.wv.syn0[indexes, :], index=tokens)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-80-a185de0b1b16> in <module>
----> 1 word_vec_df = pd.DataFrame(word_vec.wv.syn0[indexes, :], index=tokens)

AttributeError: 'KeyedVectors' object has no attribute 'syn0'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `word_vec.wv.vectors` instead of `word_vec.wv.syn0`. That's the array holding the raw vectors.

(`KeyedVectors` hasn't had a true `syn0` for a while but if it might have had a backward-compatibility alias at the time your code was 1st crafted.)

Comment: Thanks so much, you are absolutely right, it was from old code